# Slick MappedColumnType

Tags: scala, schema, slick

I would like to add a case class SupplierID to my code. And I would like to simplify the `*` method by auto-Mapping SupplierID and Int Types.

```
  case class SupplierID(id: Int)

  case class Supplier(id: SupplierID, name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String)
  // Definition of the SUPPLIERS table using case class
  class Suppliers(tag: Tag)  extends Table[Supplier](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
    def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
    def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
    def street = column[String]("STREET")
    def city = column[String]("CITY")
    def state = column[String]("STATE")
    def zip = column[String]("ZIP")

    def * ={
      (id, name, street, city, state, zip).shaped.<>({ tuple => Supplier.apply(SupplierID(tuple._1), tuple._2, tuple._3, tuple._4, tuple._5, tuple._6 )}, {
        (s : Supplier) => Some{(s.id.id, s.name, s.street, s.city, s.state, s.zip)}
      })
    }

  }
```

I'm trying to implement a column Type like this

```
 // And a ColumnType that maps it to Int
  implicit val SupplierIDColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[SupplierID, Int](
     s => s.id,    // map Bool to Int
     i => SupplierID(i) // map Int to Bool
  )
```

How to use such mappingtype ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
case class SupplierID(id: Int)

  // And a ColumnType that maps it to Int
  implicit val SupplierIDColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[SupplierID, Int](
     s => s.id,    // map SupplierID to Int
     i => SupplierID(i) // map Int to SupplierID
  )

  case class Supplier(id: SupplierID, name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String)
  // Definition of the SUPPLIERS table using case class
  class Suppliers(tag: Tag)  extends Table[Supplier](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
    def id = column[SupplierID]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
    def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")


       def street = column[String]("STREET")
        def city = column[String]("CITY")
        def state = column[String]("STATE")
        def zip = column[String]("ZIP")

        def * = (id, name, street, city, state, zip) <>(Supplier.tupled , Supplier.unapply _)

  }
```

Comment: What is the type of SupplierIDColumnType? I get a warning if the type is not defined explicitly.